# Proper way for timed redirects

Tags: php, redirect

I'm kind of confused... HTML `<meta>` redirects are discouraged, PHP `header();` redirects are discouraged too (at least random user on PHP.net [says so](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#99214)), javascript redirects are good, but won't work if user has disabled it. Have to agree, that disabled javascript nowadays is pretty rare, but still.

So in this case, what would be the best way to do timed redirects? Like, the one that could be considered valid, all platforms compatible etc.

And, any references for W3 discouraged PHP `header();` redirects? Or it's discouraged because of it acts exactly the same as `<meta>` redirect?

P.S. Would love to see how you guys get your timed redirects done for the best accessibility.

**EDIT:** It's needed for redirects after form submission.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [php script to stay for few second in some page  and redirect ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768573/php-script-to-stay-for-few-second-in-some-page-and-redirect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3C Article is no solution, if you need a **timed** redirect. Timed redirects are generally discouraged, since *the website does something without any User-Action*, which can be considered to be bad UI design. 
If you really need a timed redirect go for the Meta-Refresh stuff.

Comment: Maybe bad UX design instead UI design?

Comment: Why use a meta refresh when you can also send the same refresh header using `header()`?