# header() with delay not working in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header

I can't get...

```
<?php
   header( "Refresh: 5; URL=http://www.mywebsite.com" );
?>
```

...working in Internet Explorer (damn you!).

It works great in Chrome and if I use...

```
header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com");
```

...it works in both, but I get no delay.

Comment: If you need a delay, just use meta refresh, or JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP header("Refresh") problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884365/php-headerrefresh-problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including it as a meta tag, or reloading via JavaScript.

Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = new function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I ended up with location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com" instead since I wanted it to redirect and not refresh :)